# Can't seem to close tinymce 4 popup from a custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, tinymce

I have created a custom plugin inside of tinyMCE 4. It pops up a modal window and displays images in a said directory. You pick the image, then it adds it to the content and closes the popup. I have it inserting the image into the content, but I can't seem to close the popup. I've tried many different ways and none of them work.

One of the errors I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'win' of undefined
```

That's happening with the current code which follows:

**Plugin:**

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('imageuploads', function(editor, url) {
// Add a button that opens a window
editor.addButton('imageuploads', {
    text: 'Insert Image',
    icon: false,
    onclick: function() {
        // Open window
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: "Insert Uploaded Image",
            url: 'insertimage.php',
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            inline: true,
            close_previous: "yes"
        });
    }
});
});
```

**Plugin File:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-image-url').bind('click', function(){
        var image_url = $('.image_choice:checked').val();
        var insert_url = '<img src="/editor/uploads/' + image_url + '">';

        parent.tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent(insert_url);
        parent.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close(this);
    });
});
```

There is some HTML before that, but all it is is the images listed out with a radio input to determine which one is selected. Inserting works, but I can't seem to close the popup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

The errors are coming from tinymce.js on line #22746, so the close() method is getting called. It just can't see the popup for some reason.

Comment: It's better if you could post the solution as Answer and accept your own solution.

Comment: Ah ... good call. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with the following:

```
var ed = parent.tinymce.editors[0];
ed.windowManager.windows[0].close();
```

So, now my jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('.image_choice').bind('click', function(){
    var image_url = $('.image_choice:checked').val();
    var insert_url = '<img src="/editor/uploads/' + image_url + '">';

    parent.tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent(insert_url);

    var ed = parent.tinymce.editors[0];
    ed.windowManager.windows[0].close();
});
```

I hope this helps someone that runs into the same problem. This one puzzled me for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, if your page has more than two TinyMCE editors:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
```

I used it for TinyMCE 4.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this for while too. I tried to implement TinyMCE 4: http://www.roxyfileman.com/ for MVC.

Changing this code helps me: win.tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.close(); / win.tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.windows[1].close();

In my case when I selected file, wrong popup get closed. Maybe it helps to someone ;)

Answer (score -2):

try to use thi code `

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var parentWin = (!window.frameElement && window.dialogArguments) ||     opener ||     parent || top;
 $(function() {
 $('img').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
imgAlt = $(this).attr('alt');
divInput =                 $("input#"+parentWin.inputSrc,parent.document).parent().attr('id');
divInputSplit = divInput.split("_");
divTitle = "mce_"+(parseInt(divInputSplit[1],10) +1);
$("input#"+parentWin.inputSrc,parent.document).val(imgSrc);
$("input#"+divTitle,parent.document).val(imgAlt);
$(".mce-close",parent.document).last().trigger("click");
});
});  
</script>
```

or visit [tinymce4 file browser](http://zrclassroom.com/toturials/tinymce4-instalation-et-configuration-du-tinymce-file-browser-ajout-des-lien-et-des-image-184) `